# How to determine lock on file geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-database

I'm trying to delete a file geodatabase through Windows Explorer but I get the error message:

```
The action can't be completed because the folder or file in it is open in another program. Close the folder and try again.
```

I have no success deleting it through right-click in ArcCatalog, or using Delete_management in a Python script. I've deleted all map services that could be using this geodatabase. I've covered issues like making sure no one else has this geodatabase open. Does anyone know how I can delete this geodatabase? Or does anyone know how I can determine what might be locking it? Quick and dirty methods are welcome.

Comment: if on a network or shared drive other users might be connected to it. Removing lock files use http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/file_ge-516860750.htm

Comment: I have same problem.i stop arcgis services then restart my computer. also check your permisions ,read only .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reset the computer and you will clear all locks, open ArcCatalog and delete the Filegeodatabase

Comment: this only works if the geodatabase is on the local computer, network drives can have active connections from other users.

Comment: Hey, thanks all for the feedback. My network people restarted the server (yep, it was a server) and I was able to delete the file geodatabase. My Friday is saved!

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot reset your computer (such as a server that is running a critical process) you can actually use Windows Explorer and delete the .LOCK file directly from the .gdb folder. You will also see, while doing this, who the culprit is (what computer), in order to track down the process that is (probably) crashing and causing the lock to remain.

If you compact a GDB through Toolbox, that will also remove all the lock files.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I will be unable to delete a geodatabase even when Arcmap is closed (verified by using Windows Task Manager). What worked for me is in Windows Task Manager, go to Processes tab, and close all the Arcmap processes that continue running even after the application has been closed. This allows me to then delete what I need to.